# Problems configuring Lasso Lab on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, lasso-lang

Trying to get LassoLab  (which is an Eclipse based IDE for lasso) to work on Windows 7.

I'm running into trouble launching a run configuration. Set it up per video here: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMTQklE3Mu0 
but it does not work.

I have Lasso 9 server with IIS installed and it runs fine.  Is anyone is doing Lasso development on Windows?

LassoTalk list is very Mac centric and I'm not getting any help there.

Comment: Andy, the LassoTalk list has a lot of Windows and Linux guys on there too :) When you created your new "lasso: project using the wizard, did you configure your interpreter?

Comment: FYI, one of the reasons you may not have got much response in the last week is the annual Lasso Developers Conference was on in Niagara Falls. Theres still quite a few devs I'm aware of taking their time getting home!

Comment: Ah that explains it :)
Yes I configured the interpreter, the IDE found lasso.exe on my drive.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's the answer for the benefit of others looking (now that via comments it's confirmed that was the issue):

When you created your new "lasso: project using the wizard, Configure your interpreter.

If you use the "search" the it will find it if installed.

This only needs to be done the first time you create a new project in Lasso Lab after installing Lasso 9 :)

Comment: I went through the tutorial and finding the interptreter was one of the steps, so yes, the interpreter is configured correctly. When I click "run" nothing happens.

Comment: Another tidbit that might be a clue : When I created a project a message in the bottom right corner says: "creating database for project xxx" This task never stops, it continues going. I can cancel it but that doe not make a difference. There is a typo - "project" is spelled "ptoject" but that's nitpicking. I just want this thing to work